# Cannot remove Docker Container from Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-desktop

I'm trying to remove a container on the Docker Desktop applicaiton. (v3.6.0 Mac)

> Cannot remove Docker Compose application. Reason: Error invoking
> remote method 'compose-action': Error: Command failed: docker-compose
> --file "docker-compose.yaml" --project-name "tos-apps" --project-directory "/Users/kunalojha/Desktop/tos-apps" down time="2021-08-22T18:40:00-05:00" level=warning msg="The "UID"
> variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
> time="2021-08-22T18:40:00-05:00" level=warning msg="The "UID"
> variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
> services.redis.user must be a string

It seems to throw this message anytime I attempt to close it. I have seen a github issue opened regarding this and closed after a new release, but i'm still facing the same issue. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 24):

This is how I solved an issue similar to this one:

Find the container id using `docker ps` - `docker ps -a` will show all containers, `docker ps -l` the last created container.

Than remove all the containers for the application individually e.g. `docker rm c52b93c43544`.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, will share two potential solutions, depending on one's goals:

1. Remove every container
2. Remove only one container

For my examples, I will be using WSL terminal on Windows. But the approach should be similar in other environments.

---

**Option 1**

If the goal is to remove all the containers, then start by stopping all containers using [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

And then remove them with [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/)

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

One can use pruning as well, depending on one's goals. See first note below.

See the last two notes for the way to remove all images and volumes.

---

**Option 2**

If the goal is to remove one specific container, start by listing all the Docker containers in one's system with

```
docker ps -a

[Out]:

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
5d5e5c233f5e   nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes               80/tcp    web-server
6f53b6c2a953   mysql:latest       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago    Exited (137) 20 hours ago            mysql-server
35c37fbf1041   redis              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago     Exited (0) 2 weeks ago              redis-server
```

Or

```
docker ps -aq

[Out]:

5d5e5c233f5e
6f53b6c2a953
35c37fbf1041
```

If the goal is to remove the `CONTAINER ID` equal to `5d5e5c233f5e`, start by stopping it with [`stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)

```
docker stop 5d5e5c233f5e
```

Finally, remove the container with [`rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/)

```
docker rm 5d5e5c233f5e
```

---

**Notes:**

- > Docker takes a conservative approach to cleaning up unused objects (often referred to as “garbage collection”), such as images, containers, volumes, and networks: these objects are generally not removed unless you explicitly ask Docker to do so. This can cause Docker to use extra disk space. For each type of object, Docker provides a prune command.

  [Read more about prune](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/)
- The [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69113472/7109869) was leading me into a

  > Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container... Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

  The error says it all. Before removing a container, one will need to stop it first.
- Additionally, one can also remove all the images with [`docker rmi`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)

  ```
  docker rmi $(docker images -q)
  ```
- And to remove the remove all the volumes that are not being used with [`docker volume prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)

  ```
  docker volume prune
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can remove main container from Docker Desktop.

Go to "Container" -> "View Details" (or just expand container) then delete the containers inside one by one.

Answer (score -4):

You can try to remove the container or containers in the cmd.exe